# Need a counter example for cycle in a graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

Could anyone give a counter example for that theorem :

> A graph G has exactly one vertex of degree $1$, then it contains a cycle.

I am so confused. I wonder that may I give a counter example which considers trees.

Comment: is it not 'a simple connected graph G with no vertices degree 1 has a cycle?'

Comment: Note that any acyclic graph must contain at least two vertices of degree $1$, and hence having exactly $1$ vertex of degree $1$ means it is cyclic

Comment: The idea is that a graph contains no cycle if and only if it's a tree, in the common sense of the word tree as a graph that can be drawn as a series of branching paths terminating in leaves. The degree one vertices are precisely the leaves and the root, and a tree has at least one leaf, so with the root that's a minimum of two vertices of degree 1.

Comment: @Jack: The root need not have degree $1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The counter example does not exist.

Let $v_1$ be a vertex of $G$ with degree $1$. Then, let $v_2$ be its neighbor. Because the degree of $v_2$ is more than $1$, $v_2$ has a neighbor that is not $v_1$. Let that neighbor be $v_3$.

Now, $v_3$ has a neighbor that is not $v_2$ (because the degree of $v_3$ is at least $2$) and is not $v_1$ (because $v_1$ has degree $1$). Let that neighbor be $v_4$.

Now, $v_4$ has a neighbor that is not $v_3$ or $v_1$. If the neighbor is $v_2$, then $v_2,v_3,v_4$ is a cycle. Otherwise the neighbor is $v_5$ and repeat until a cycle is found.

Comment: @Rinzler No, it can't be a tree. A tree has several (at least $2$, if the graph is connected) vertices of degree $1$.

Answer (score 3):

If you allow *infinite* graphs, then the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ with consecutive numbers considered adjacent is a counterexample:  the vertex $0$ has degree $1$, while all others have degree $2$, but the graph contains no cycles.

Comment: If it was allowed, your answer would be true. However, the graph $G$ is finite.

Comment: @Rinzler, you didn't specify that in the question.

Comment: I think (discrete-mathematics) refers finiteness. Anyway, thanks for responding @barrycipra

Comment: @Rinzler, not necessarily.  Discrete mathematical structures can be infinite.  But I agree, in some settings it *is* understood that one is only interested in finite objects.  Hence my "if you allow."